# LibreOffice Basic, удаление строк

Tags: vba, libre-office

Пытаюсь написать свой первый макрос, но при выполнении выдаёт ошибку:

> Ошибка времени выполнения BASIC. Переменная типа Object не установлена.

Суть макроса: удаление всех строк таблицы за исключением тех, в которых присутствуют ячейки со строковым значением s1, s2 или s3.

```
sub RemoveRow
dim iLastRow as Long
dim i as Integer
dim s1, s2, s3 as String
s1 = "Вход"
s2 = "Выход"
s3 = "Отказ"
iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'ищет последнюю заполненную строку
For i = 4 To lLastRow
    If Cells(i,5).Value = Not s1 Or Cells(i,5).Value = Not s2 Or Cells(i,5).Value = Not s3 Then Rows(i).Delete
Next    
end sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пишите макрос в LibreOffice используя синтаксис VBA Excel. Синтаксис немного разный.

Для Excel VBA:

```
Sub RemoveRow()
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim s1, s2, s3 As String

    s1 = "Вход"
    s2 = "Выход"
    s3 = "Отказ"

    iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Do While (iLastRow >= 4)
        If (Cells(iLastRow, 5) <> s1) And (Cells(iLastRow, 5) <> s2) And (Cells(iLastRow, 5) <> s3) Then
            Rows(iLastRow).Delete
        End If
        iLastRow = iLastRow - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Для LibreOffice Basic:

```
Sub RemoveRow
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim s1, s2, s3 As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim oDoc As Object

    s1 = "Вход"
    s2 = "Выход"
    s3 = "Отказ"

    oDoc = ThisComponent

    Curs = oDoc.Sheets(0).createCursor
    Curs.gotoEndOfUsedArea(True)

    iLastRow = Curs.Rows.Count

    Do While (iLastRow >= 3)
        s = oDoc.Sheets(0).getCellByPosition(4, iLastRow).getString()
        If ((s <> s1) And (s <> s2) And (s <> s3)) Then
            oDoc.Sheets(0).Rows.removeByIndex(iLastRow, 1)
        End If
        iLastRow = iLastRow - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Код конечно примитивный, но работает. И еще, индексы в Excel начинаются с 1, а в LibreOffice c 0.

Comment: думаю еще в ответе можно акцентировать внимание на том, что в таких случаях всегда нужно обходить строки снизу вверх, а не сверху вниз.

Comment: @Эдуард Измалков, спасибо верное замечание. Забыл упомянуть об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Со всеми сложностями прохода сверху вниз столкнулся, и пришел к такому коду:

```
Sub RemoveRow()
s1 = "Вход"
s2 = "Выход"
s3 = "Отказ"
i = 4
Do While Cells(i, "E").Value <> ""
        If Cells(i, "E").Value <> s1 And Cells(i, "E").Value <> s2 And Cells(i, "E").Value <> s3 Then
                Rows(i).Delete
                i = i - 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
Loop
End sub
```

Раз 5 проверял этот макрос на различных таблицах, результат полностью устраивал. Может быть тут есть какие-то подводные камни?
А с макросами в Libre я понял, что пока лучше не связываться, а изучить хотя бы VBA.

Comment: Вы не учитываете того, что среди значений может быть пустая строка (а в условии не сказано, что этого быть не может). Ваш код остановится на этой строке.